# Sitecore Commerce Analytics Errors

Tags: sitecore-commerce

I have installed and configured the Sitecore Demo Retail site on top of Sitecore Commerce 8.2.1.

I have been having issues with the commerce page events and analytics. I cannot seem to get any data in the experience analytics reports tab

Below are the Error in Logs (This happens when Checkout process is completed)

> ERROR Event custom value key 'ExternalId' could not be found. ERROR
>   Event custom value key 'ShopName' could not be found. ERROR Event
>   custom value key 'Total' could not be found. ERROR [Experience
>   Analytics]: SegmentProcessor failed to process interaction
>   '4c0f5d2b-8b18-41bc-bff8-50ade2db6ed0' segment
>   '5505a370-dcb2-4772-8574-000f6c3ddb5c' -
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. at
>   Sitecore.Commerce.ExperienceAnalytics.Models.OrderModel..ctor(OrderGoalAnalyticsData
>   analyticsData) at
>   Sitecore.Commerce.ExperienceAnalytics.Dimensions.ByOrder.GetOrderModels(PageData
>   pageData) at
>   Sitecore.Commerce.ExperienceAnalytics.Dimensions.ByOrder.d__2.MoveNext()
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() at
>   Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Pipeline.SegmentProcessor.ProcessSegments(AggregationPipelineArgs
>   args, IEnumerable`1 segments)

Answer (score 5):

I managed to find out the root cause of this issue

Sitecore Commerce has a lot of goals and events being triggered programatically, My issue was that the goal "Visitor Order Created" was checked on the "Order Confirmation Page" and this was causing the goal to be triggered twice (Once programatically and other through the UI)

I had to uncheck the goal in content editor and then this seem to solve the issue.

I have added detailed notes here in the blog post
https://blog.horizontalintegration.com/2017/11/25/sitecore-commerce-8-2-1-analytics-issue/